How Do I get access tokens for MPESA STK in Nodejs?
I am trying to integrate MPESA payment with Nodejs. However, I am uanble to get past the get access token function as am getting a 400 bad request with null data.
Here is my paymentController function. First, is a middleware function to get access tokens from safaricom url. The STK post API will only be executed if the get access token function is succesfull. However, Postman returns 400 bad request when I run the get access token route.
const axios = require('axios');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: 'backend/config/config.env' })


exports.accessToken= catchAsyncErrors(async(req, res, next) => {

   const secret = process.env.MPESA_CONSUMER_SECRET;
   const consumer = process.env.MPESA_CONSUMER_KEY;

   const auth = new Buffer.from(`${consumer}:${secret}`).toString("base64");

   await axios.get(
       "https://api.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials",
       {
           headers: {
               Authorization: `Basic ${auth}`,
           },
       }
   ) .then((data)=>{
       console.log(data.data);
       next();
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
       console.log(err);
       res.status(400).json(err.message);
     });

})


exports.stk = catchAsyncErrors(async(req, res, next) => {
   const phone = req.body.phone;
   const amount = req.body.amount;

  const date = new Date();
   const timestamp = 
   date.getFullYear() +
   ("0" + (date.getMonth() +1)).slice(-2) +
   ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) +
   ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) +
   ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
   ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2) ;

   const shortcode = "174379";
   const passkey = "bfb279f9aa9bdbcf158e97dd71a467cd2e0c893059b10f78e6b72ada1ed2c919";

   const password = new Buffer.from(shortcode + passkey + timestamp).toString("base64");

   await axios.post(
       "https://api.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest",

       {    
           BusinessShortCode: shortcode,    
           Password: password,    
           Timestamp: timestamp,    
           TransactionType: "CustomerPayBillOnline",    
           Amount: amount,    
           PartyA:`254${phone}`,    
           PartyB:shortcode,    
           PhoneNumber:`254${phone}`,    
           CallBackURL: "https://example.com/pat",    
           AccountReference:`254${phone}`,    
           TransactionDesc:"Test",
        },

        {
           headers: {
               Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
           },
        }

   ).then((data)=>{
       console.log(data);
       res.status(200).json(data);
   }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err.message);
       res.status(400).json(err.message);
   }) ;
}) ;

Here is my payment routes folder.
const router = express.Router();

const { 
stk, accessToken
} = require('../controllers/paymentController')

const { isAuthenticatedUser, authorizeRoles } = require('../middlewares/auth');


router.route('/stk').post(isAuthenticatedUser,  stk);
router.route('/token').get(isAuthenticatedUser,  accessToken);


module.exports = router

Anyone who has succefully done it in 2024, share your insights.
